# ffmpeg: Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'png', auto-selecting format 'rgb24'

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of .png files

```
file_000.png
file_005.png
file_010.png
```

I am using an inherited ffmpeg script to stitch together .png files into an .mp4 file. I don't understand all the flags, but I've used this script successfully in the past

```
## images_to_movie.sh
set -o noglob

in_files=$1
out_file=$2

ffmpeg \
    -framerate 10 \
    -loglevel warning \
    -pattern_type glob -i $in_files \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -vf 'crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2:0:0' \
    -y \
    $out_file
```

with the command

```
./images_to_movie file_*.png files.mp4
```

I am now receiving the error

> Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'png', auto-selecting
>   format 'rgb24'

Some searching reveals that

```
-pix_fmt yuv420p
```

is deprecated and I should instead use

```
-pix_fmt yuv420p -color_range 2
```

but the error remains. I tried using

```
-pix_fmt rgb24
```

and the error disappears but I'm no .mp4 file is created.

How do I need to modify this script to create an .mp4 ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there's a relationship between no output file being created and the error you previously fixed? That is to say -- why not ignore the already-fixed error, ask about the form of your code that has that error fixed, and focus *only* on no output file being created?

Comment: One important issue here: `set -o noglob` stops globs from being expanded **after your script starts**. However, when you run `./images_to_movie file_*.png files.mp4`, that glob is expanded **before** `images_to_movie` runs at all, so you end up with `$1` being the first file `file_*.png` expands to, and `$2` being the second.

Comment: ...so your second .png file is presumably being replaced with a .mp4 output. BTW, if you traced your script with `bash -x ./images_to_movie file_*.png files.mp4` logging each line to stderr as it runs, you could see that in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's Going Wrong

`file_*.png` isn't being passed to your program at all -- neither is `files.mp4`.

Instead, when you run `./images_to_movie file_*.png files.mp4`, what your shell *actually invokes* is `./images_to_movie file_000.png file_005.png file_010.png files.mp4`.

Thus, `file_000.png` is treated as the only input file, and `file_005.png` is treated as the output file to use. The extra arguments (`file_010.png` and `files.mp4`) are in positions `$3` and `$4`; are never read; and are thus ignored entirely.

---

#### How To Fix It

The original code assumes that `./images_to_movie file_*.png files.mp4` will put `file_*.png` in `$1` and `files.mp4` in `$2`. Unless `file_*.png` has no matches, that assumption is false.

`set -o noglob` prevents glob expansion from taking place *after* your script is started, but nothing in your script's contents can prevent the *calling script* from expanding globs beforehand. Thus, you want an invocation *with quotes*, akin to:

```
./images_to_movie 'file_*.png' files.mp4
```

...and script contents akin to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

in_files=$1
out_file=$2

ffmpeg \
    -framerate 10 \
    -loglevel warning \
    -pattern_type glob -i "$in_files" \
    -pix_fmt rgb24 \
    -vf 'crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2:0:0' \
    -y \
    "$out_file"
```

Note that we took out the `noglob`, and instead quoted all expansions; this not only prevents globbing, but also prevents string-splitting -- so a pattern like `File *.png` wouldn't be split into one word `File` and a second word `*.png` even in the absence of globbing.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you. Also, with the proper syntax to prevent globbing, I am no longer receiving the -pix_fmt yuv420p error.